# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

In my Application I have used lots of images on TableView Listing, So that I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` also my application crashed in android emulator. Anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

titanium doest not recommend using table view for listing when you are building for android.

instead use scrollview.

by using table view you may also get into textfield focus-lost problem and also titanium has known tableView scroll performance issue

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-1821

a better approach is to use low resolution images in scrollview and use proper javascript structure and break your code into small functions. 
try to remove unnecessary event handlers i.e image "load" event

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to use smaller images. Make sure that you don't scale them down. Resize them instead.

Comment: I am already using small size images only (between 4kb to 6kb) in png format

Comment: I'm not sure how they are stored when you load them into the memory. What's your images resolution and color deepth?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions for avoiding this error:
1. Use jpg images instead of png (jpgs are smaller in size)
2. Try to keep your runtime memory minimum by finishing the activities which are not being used.
3. Use DDMS to moniter your runtime memory usage

Comment: hi, i am using around 25 images in one page, Image size are between 4kb to 6kb.How do I keep keep my runtime memory minimum?